# Javascript works in IE 8, but not Firefox 30

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, getelementbyid

The below function does what I want it to in IE 8 but not Firefox 30.  The intent is that checking the skill box should enable the user to modify the quantity textbox, and that unchecking it should restore the original value and make it readonly again.

```
function updateQuantity(refNum) {
  var quantity = 'quantity' + refNum;
  var startQuantity = 'startQuantity' + refNum;
  var skill = 'skill' + refNum;

  if (!document.getElementById(skill).checked){
    document.getElementById(quantity).disabled = true;
    document.getElementById(quantity).readOnly = true;
    document.getElementById(quantity).style.color = "rgb(192,192,192)";
    document.getElementById(quantity).value = document.getElementById(startQuantity).value;
  } else {
    document.getElementById(quantity).disabled = false;
    document.getElementById(quantity).readOnly = false;
    document.getElementById(quantity).style.color = "rgb(0,0,0)";
  }
}
```

Here is an HTML snippet that exercises the functions.

```
<tr><td>Toughness</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>10 ^ (100 total)</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="skill8" value="Toughness" onclick="updateQuantity(8);updateTotal(8);">
  <input style="color:rgb(192,192,192);" disabled readonly type="text" name="quantity8" maxlength="2" size="2" value="4" onclick="updateTotal(8);">
  <input type="hidden" name="startQuantity8" value="4"></td></tr>
<tr style="background:rgb(80,30,30);"><td>Light Armor</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>20</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="skill9" value="Light Armor" onclick="updateQuantity(9);updateTotal(9);">
  <input style="color:rgb(192,192,192);" disabled readonly type="text" name="quantity9" maxlength="2" size="2" value="1" onclick="updateTotal(9);">
  <input type="hidden" name="startQuantity9" value="1"></td></tr>
```

I've tried moving the script definition to the end of the  section, but that doesn't resolve the problem.  I'm getting the error in the Firefox debugger that document.getElementById(skill) is null when I'm trying to evaluate it in the if statement.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Where are your `id`s? In FF you really have to have ids. `name !== id`.

Comment: `name="skill8"` != `id="skill8"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Firefox is correct, there is no element with such an **ID**. From the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536437(v=vs.85).aspx):

> In IE7 Standards mode and previous modes, this method performs a case-insensitive match on both the **ID** and **NAME** attributes, which might produce unexpected results. For more information, see [Defining Document Compatibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx).

And look at your HTML, that seems what is happening:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="skill8" ... />
```

**Possible solutions**:

- Add an `id` attribute to all the elements you wish to refer to via `getElementById`.
- Use [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName) instead.

Comment: Oops!  Renaming all of the 'name=' to 'id=' solved it.  Thanks!